# At the bytecode level, how does Java's Class.getEnumConstants() know which classes are enum classes?

Tags: java, reflection, enums, jvm-bytecode

The Java reflection API contains a method `Class.getEnumConstants()` that makes it possible to determine whether or not a class is an `enum` class (it returns `null` if it doesn't think the class is an `enum`), and what its constants are.

I'm working on a program that generates JVM bytecode directly, and am trying to generate an enum class. As such, I need to know how Java recognises enum classes from their bytecode, so that `getEnumConstants` will work correctly. Obviously, the class needs to extend `Enum`, but that clearly isn't enough on its own (e.g. the bytecode corresponding to `public class Example extends Enum<Example> {}` will not be recognised as an `enum`); what other features does the JVM bytecode for a class need to have so that Java's reflection API will recognise it as a Java `enum`, and be able to determine its enum constants?

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.16.1 may give you some pointers.

Comment: Set  `ACC_ENUM`, see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to compile an `enum` type, you have to mark the class with the [`ACC_ENUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.1-200-E) flag in the class’ access flags.

Further, for each constant, you have to create a corresponding `public static final` field which is also marked with [`ACC_ENUM`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.5-200-A.1) in the field’s access flags.

Then, you need a [class initializer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-2.html#jvms-2.9.2) (a no-arg `void` method named `<clinit>`) which creates instances and assigns them to the fields.

But that’s not enough. Mind [the language specification](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se12/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.3), which specifies the existence of the two implicitly declared methods

> ```
>   /**
>   * Returns an array containing the constants of this enum 
>   * type, in the order they're declared.  This method may be
>   * used to iterate over the constants as follows:
>   *
>   *    for(E c : E.values())
>   *        System.out.println(c);
>   *
>   * @return an array containing the constants of this enum 
>   * type, in the order they're declared
>   */
>   public static E[] values();
>
>   /**
>   * Returns the enum constant of this type with the specified
>   * name.
>   * The string must match exactly an identifier used to declare
>   * an enum constant in this type.  (Extraneous whitespace 
>   * characters are not permitted.)
>   * 
>   * @return the enum constant with the specified name
>   * @throws IllegalArgumentException if this enum type has no
>   * constant with the specified name
>   */
>   public static E valueOf(String name);
> ```

It’s the duty of the compiler resp. bytecode generating tool to insert their implementation to the specific enum type. Note that despite being compiler generated, these two method [should not get marked as synthetic](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se13/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.8).

---

The specification does not address, how Reflection will gather its information. It could iterate over the marked fields and read them, to assemble an array or it could just invoke the `values()` method of the specific type. So you can not omit any of these artifacts nor can you implement the `values()` method by just delegate to `Class.getEnumConstants()`.